# Overriding default search location for library on Ubuntu 12.04.1

Tags: 12.04, paths

To properly compile the `mpfr` library on my Ubuntu 12.04.1 system (64-bit), I need to update the `C_INCLUDE_PATH`, `LIBRARY_PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_RUN_PATH` variables.  This is mentioned in the [FAQ](http://www.mpfr.org/faq.html#undef_ref1) for building the `mpfr` library.  Updating these variables is required since the `gmp` library is already on the search paths and included as a part of the default Ubuntu install.  However, I've installed the `gmp` library in my `/usr/local/lib` directory.

In my home directory, I've created a `.pam_environment` file and placed the following lines:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include:$C_INCLUDE_PATH
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_RUN_PATH
```

However, the `mpfr` library `configure` script still can't find my own version of the `gmp` library in the `/usr/local/lib` directory.

Looking inside of the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` directory, the contents of my `libc.conf` file is:

```
# libc default configuration
/usr/local/lib
```

Also, the contents of the `x86_64-linux-gnu.conf` file is:

```
# Multiarch support
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

However, running `locate libgmp` on the command line shows that there is already a version of libgmp that ships with the system.

```
$ locate libgmp
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.0.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libgmp.so
/usr/share/doc/libgmp10
/usr/share/doc/libgmp10/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/libgmp10/TODO.Debian
/usr/share/doc/libgmp10/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libgmp10/copyright
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgmp10:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgmp10:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgmp10:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgmp10:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgmp10:amd64.shlibs
```

Questions:

1. How do I override the location of the `libgmp` version used during linking?  I would like to use the library in the `\usr\local\lib` directory.
2. Do I place the `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and other variables in my `.pam_environment` file, or is there a more appropriate location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution to this problem appears to be installing the library in another location:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/usr/local
```

Then, the library in this directory is selected when linking.  Another possibility would be to rename `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl-1.0.0/engines/libgmp.so` to something else, but this is not especially clever if the library is used by a program installed on the system.